# Adding Custom menu to Visual Studio-2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

I have built a custom menu command (Launch Application1) using Visual studio SDK-13(using C# extensibility) which pops up in the 'Tools' menu of Visual studio.

Now, when I run this project a new instance of Visual studio opens up and 'Launch Application1' is shown under the 'Tools' menu of that visual studio.

The output is a '.dll' file and not an '.exe' but I want to have an installer for this, so that a simple installation can deploy this into any visual studio environment permanently. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The output of a visual studio extension - in your case a custom menu command is always a dll file, with the dll file visual studio also creates a VSIX file which is a Zip file and contains the dll and some other manifest files.

The VSIX file can directly be distributed for installation on other systems, If the correct version visual studio is installed, the extension will be installed with that.

For basic stuff you can use the VSIX as your redistributable. If you want to have a proper MSI file you can try WiX installer.

Comment: I don't see a VSIX file, i can see a file with extension '.vsixmanifest'. This file didn't show up any installer on other Visual studio. Can you please give some more info regarding this?

Comment: I guess you have not enabled VSIX creation. To enable that do the following. Open your project properties -> Go to the VSIX tab -> check the option - "Create VSIX Container during build". you can also check the option "Deploy VSIX content to experimental instance for debugging" to install the created VSIX in the experimental instance. Hope this helps.

Comment: That didn't help.. Can anyone at least tell me how to use command line arguments within a project?

Comment: That is a bummer... It should have worked... did you see a VSIX tab in project property pages? Anyway, Check this site to create a VSIX manually.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407026.aspx